# Call click function only for TH with class

Tags: jquery

I have table

```
<table id="dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>TH 1</th>
        <th>TH 2</th>
        <th class="sortable">TH 3</th>
        <th>TH 4</th>
        <th>TH 5</th>
        <th class="sortable">TH 6</th>
        <th>TH 7</th>
        <th>TH 8</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need solution for add class into TD only under TH with class "sortable" but only If I click only to TH with class sortable.

Now I use Jquery code

```
$("#dataTable th").click(function () {
    if ($("th").hasClass("sortable") {
        // has specialclass 
        var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));

        $('tr').find('td.td-sorting').removeClass('td-sorting');
        $('tr').find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')').addClass('td-sorting');
    }
});
```

This part of code works fine:

```
var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));

        $('tr').find('td.td-sorting').removeClass('td-sorting');
        $('tr').find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')').addClass('td-sorting');
    }
```

But not works call function only for TH with class "sortable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if ($("th").hasClass("sortable") {` does a new "parse", resulting in all ths from the page. One of them has the class, so the condition will be true.

Just add your class to the original css selector:

```
$("#dataTable th.sortable").click(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$('th.sortable').click(function(){
   $(this)
   .closest('thead') // find thead
   .next() // tbody
   .find('tr td') // td
   .eq($(this).index()) // access by index
   .addClass("td-sorting"); // add class
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this:

```
$('th.sortable').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('table').find('td').removeClass('td-sorting');
  $(this).parents('table').find('td').eq($(this).index()).addClass("td-sorting");
});
```